# How you use conditions on pandas on different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find top-5 delayed routes from all flights, then count all flights with weather conditions contributing to a delay. 
Using this code I can get the top five delayed routes

```
    flights_df.groupby(['Origin','Dest','WeatherDelay', flights_df.DepDelay>0])['WeatherDelay'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(5)
```

**Dataframe**
[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sId6P.jpg)
here is the output

```
    Origin  Dest  WeatherDelay  DepDelay
    LAX     SFO   0.0           True        3261
    ORD     LGA   0.0           True        3136
    ATL     LGA   0.0           True        2900
    SFO     LAX   0.0           True        2889
    LGA     ORD   0.0           True        2640
         Name: WeatherDelay, dtype: int64
```

How will I put the condtion WeatherDelay>0 to get top 5 routes delay by weather?

Here is the catch: I have origin and destination. I have to form routes, then find number of delayed routes. Also I've to find the number of flights delayed by weather from those 5 routes.

Comment: Can  you please show us the DataFrame you have.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select what you need from your dataframe before grouping them:

```
flights_df[(flights_df.DepDelay > 0) & (flights_df.WeatherDelay > 0)].groupby(['Origin','Dest','WeatherDelay'])['WeatherDelay'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(5)
```

Wrap your conditions in parenthesis `(flights_df.DepDelay > 0) & (flights_df.WeatherDelay > 0)`

If you want the top 5 by routes, you should group by your route definition, in this case group by Origin and Destination.

```
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)

df[(df.DepDelay > 0) & (df.WeatherDelay > 0)].groupby(['Origin','Dest'])['Origin'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(5)
```

Comment: It worked but the output I'm getting is way off than what I expect. Does it mean I'm getting the wrong routes?

Comment: Do you think you can post your source data? Or a sample if it's too big? I wont be able to know what you mean by way off.

Comment: What about the notebook?

Comment: Post where your data source is or sample, the notebook itself will not give people an idea of what data it holds if you are pulling it off a local file.

Comment: the data source ==> http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/2008.csv.bz2

Comment: I see LGA to DEN with 5.0 Weather Delay and 27 trips with my answer. Does this not do what you need then?

Comment: the number of weather of weather delays from the 5 delayed routes is more than that. should be one of this 449, 539, 549, 668

Comment: Do not have your specific numbers, but your Weather Delay should be removed from your group by if you are only interested in routes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make multiple conditions when indexing you can use:

```
dataframe[(dataframe["column1"] > condition1) & (dataframe["column2"] > condition2)]
```

You can use & for and, | for or.

You can also look into `np.where()`

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to took the example to get this:

```
>>> mdf
    Name Product  Sale  Number
0   jack  Apples    34       1
1   Riti  Mangos    31       2
2   Aadi  Grapes    30       3
3  Sonia  Apples    32       4
4   Lucy  Mangos    33       5
5   Mike  Apples    35       6
```

So, i took the if `Sale` is greater than 31 & `Number` is ge 3 then print the DataFrame..

```
>>> mdf[ (mdf['Sale'] > 31) & (mdf['Number'] >3) ]
    Name Product  Sale  Number
3  Sonia  Apples    32       4
4   Lucy  Mangos    33       5
5   Mike  Apples    35       6
```

Data Provided by link:

```
>>> df[ (df['DepDelay'] !=0 ) & (df['WeatherDelay'] !=0) ].head()
  DepDelay Origin Dest WeatherDelay
0        8    IAD  TPA
1       19    IAD  TPA
2        8    IND  BWI
3       -4    IND  BWI
5       25    IND  JAX
```

Comment: I have origin and destination. I have to form routes, then find number of delayed routes. Also I've to find the number of flights delayed by weather from those 5 routes.

Comment: Please try .. `df[ (df['DepDelay'] !=0 ) & (df['WeatherDelay'] !=0) ]` , this works for me by reproducing the data from your csv file.